# SQL Query (DROP/SELECT/ALTER etc ) on Table - "ERROR CODE 2013 : LOST connection to MYSQL server during query "

Tags: mysql

I am continuously getting "error code 2013 :lost connection to mysql server error" on only one table which has only 96 rows.
I increased the read timeout from 30s to 60s and then 600s.
Any sql query performed on this table e.g. DROP/TRUNCATE/SELECT/ALTER gives same error.

I don't think it should be read timeout time maintained in the preferences of MYSQL Workbench.
Please help.

Comment: Issue automatically got resolved. Still not sure why it was in there at first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this (temporary solution):

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=10;
```

The standard value is 10, the minimum value is 2, the maximum is 31536000.

This method will only work until you restart your mysql server, to make a definitive solution you must change the mysql server configuration file.

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

> [mysqld] 
>   connect_timeout=10

Reference: https://ixnfo.com/en/change-connect_timeout-in-mysql.html

Comment: I get error error code 1227 on this. although i have all the privileges. Also, this is happening for just one table of the schema. Others are working fine.

Comment: @VISHWARANJAN Have you tried changing the configuration file?